# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable ( when importing selenium )

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver, typeerror

i have problem when running this code :

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
driver = webdriver.firefox()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

i have searched for the problem and i got some results. but unfortunately , they didn't work. So , how can i solve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have made a typo.

```
webdriver.Firefox()
```

Note the capital F.

Answer (score 5):

the same goes for other browsers!

e.g.

```
webdriver.chrome Vs. webdriver.Chrome
```

(its even harder to notice this!)

thanks so much for the help! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome.

driver = Chrome()
```

When typing "Chrome" Note the capital C.

You probably gonna need to specify the executable_path for chromedriver.exe:

```
driver = Chrome(executable_path="path_in_here")
```

Comment: I have kept the chromedriver.exe in the same folder as my project and it works without adding the path explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

......implies that your program is trying to call a python module.

---

You  need a minor modification in the offending line of code. You have used:

```
driver = webdriver.firefox()
```

Where as *`firefox`* is a ***module*** for example as in:

```
selenium.webdriver.firefox.options
```

So you have to change `firefox()` to **`Firefox()`** and your effective line of code will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Likewise:

- For *Chrome*:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  ```
- For *Internet Explorer*:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Ie()
  ```