# Python - Web Scraping - Selenium - AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a code in Python for Web Scraping and fetching HTML table but its throwing an Attribute Error : 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

**FULL ERROR**
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rajat.kapoor\PycharmProjects\RajatProject\FirstPythonFile.py", line 6, in 
scheme = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[0]')

**Given Below is the Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.mutualfundssahihai.com/en/schemeperformance')
driver.maximize_window()
scheme = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[0]')
benchmark = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[1]')
result=[]
for i in range(len(riskometer)):
    temporary_data = {'Scheme':scheme.text,
                      'Benchmark':benchmark.text}
    result.append(temporary_data)

df_data = pd.DataFrame(result)
df_data.to_excel('scrapingresult.xlsx',index=False)
```

I tried writing the code for Web Scraping using Selenium (fetch HTML Table) but its throwing an Attribute Error :'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

**FULL ERROR**

DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rajat.kapoor\PycharmProjects\RajatProject\FirstPythonFile.py", line 6, in 
scheme = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[0]')

Below is the code for the same

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.mutualfundssahihai.com/en/schemeperformance')
driver.maximize_window()
scheme = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[0]')
benchmark = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[1]')
result=[]
for i in range(len(riskometer)):
    temporary_data = {'Scheme':scheme.text,
                      'Benchmark':benchmark.text}
    result.append(temporary_data)

df_data = pd.DataFrame(result)
df_data.to_excel('scrapingresult.xlsx',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

The same issue can be seen here [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable ( when importing selenium )](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16626734/12071682).

The line,

```py
driver = webdriver.chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
```

should be,

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
```

notice the capital 'C' in Chrome.

Additionally use

```py
driver.find_element("xpath", "#path_selector")
```

as find_elements_by_xpath is removed.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek I corrected it but it is still showing the error as : DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rajat.kapoor\PycharmProjects\RajatProject\FirstPythonFile.py", line 6, in <module>
    scheme = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[0]')
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

Comment: Try using driver.find_element("xpath", "'//tbody/tr/td[0]').

The function find_elements_by_xpath was deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72754651/12071682